# Reading in data from a file and using it to create a new object

Tags: java, file

I have a class called Name like so.

```
public Name (String first, String last)
```

This is a text file that contains names, its filename is "names.txt".

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

The file called "names.txt" is read in like so.

```
File read = new File ("names.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(read);
```

I want to know how to automatically create a new name object using the first word (John) as the first parameter and the second word (Doe) as the second parameter.

How do I do this?

Comment: I know how to read files.

Comment: Do you know how to instantiate objects? If yes I think you're capable. :)

Comment: I do know how to instantiate objects, what I don't know is how to handle any of the data that is being read in.

Comment: I recommend using a lib that reads the entire file pre-split into lines, such as apache commons io, and then split each line on the whitespace.  Of course, using split on newline to separate lines is not too hard itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll help you out. The line you want is

```
Name n = new Name(in.next(), in.next());
```

It's that simple, although this is not a particularly robust way.

Comment: This doesn't avoid issues of improperly formatted lines.  For example, a line with 4 words will be translated into two names.

Comment: Yes, *this is not a particularly robust way*. But really if OP is asking a question like this I think it's all that's needed.

Comment: Is there a way to edit this line of code so that it follows format? 
For example if the first and last name always had a tab between them.

Comment: @user2778506 I think `next()` handles all whitespace correctly. If you want better formatting you'll want to capture whole lines though.

Answer (score 0):

read the file using scanner and include the split portion

```
  //while(scanner) iterate the scanner upto end of the file read every line
    {
      String[] splitResult = input.split(" ");
      firstName = splitResult[0];
      lastName = splitResult[1];
      storeMethod(firstName,lastName);   // use this method to store the first name and last name
   }
```